# Autosizing a UIView that contains a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I have a UITableViewController with a UIView before the table view. The UIView (`IBOutlet UIView *templateDescriptionView`) has a UITextView (`IBOutlet UITextView *templateDescription`) in it. It looks like this:

[image: UITableView with UIView and nested UITextView]

The UITextView can have a variable amount of text. I'm trying to programmatically resize the UITextView and UIView to compensate for this, but it's not working as expected.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [templateDescription sizeToFit];

    CGRect frame = templateDescription.frame;
    frame.size.height = templateDescription.contentSize.height;
    templateDescription.frame = frame;

    CGRect viewFrame =  templateDescriptionView.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height = templateDescription.contentSize.height + 40; // 40 for padding
    templateDescriptionView.frame = viewFrame;
}
```

The problem is, when everything renders, the UIView is partially on top of the UITableView. It resizes, but it's not resizing to the proper height. What am I doing wrong? This is Xcode 5, iOS7.

Comment: Why are u resizing a UITextView ?? Isnt it scrollable by default ??

Comment: I want it to fill up the area without needing to scroll it.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I misunderstood your meaning. But UITableViewController is used to control a UITableView. Does it run well that a UITableViewController control a UIView? Maybe you put a UIView into the HeaderInSection of tableView. In iOS7, **self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;** can be used to remove the space inset in scrollview.